# How to create and pass a COM IDispatch pointer as callback from a C++ Console Client to a C++ WinService successfully?

Tags: c++, com, callback, console-application, idispatch

In advance sorry for the TOO Long post, but given that there are many parts involved, and I am not sure where I can be making a mistake, hence, I need to post all the parts involved. Please do not assume anything, I can be making any type of error here.

Problem:

1) Real problem: Just learning COM.

2) I need to pass a IDispatch pointer from my console client (**ConsoleClient**) in C++ as parameter to a COM function in a Windows Service (**WinService**). This IDispatch pointer acts as callback. The WinService knows the name of the function to be called. All my attempts have been unsuccessulf. I am getting different errors like: No implemented, RPC is unavailable, etc..

**NOTE:** The following error is correct! I edited after @Igor pointed out my error: to have a do-while (which I removed from the main()) in a STA thread. I added a message pump (GetMessage, TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage) in the main() thread (instead of the do-while) and my problem was fixed!

I have a WinService exposing the following COM interface (WinService's idl file):

```
[
object,
uuid(DBE8BC31-9D2B-4F4B-903A-B40473408DE9),
dual,
nonextensible,
pointer_default(unique)
]
interface IWinService : IDispatch
{
///Here there are more functions..
    [id(4), helpstring("Interface HELP")] 
    HRESULT WinServiceCOMfunction( [in] VARIANT vCallback, [out, retval] LONG* pReturn );
    //Here there even more functions...
 };  

[
    uuid(DEF3BFAE-ADF4-493B-8D01-E47A279225C5),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("LIB HELP")
]
library WinServiceLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");

[       
    uuid(AC290DC9-8CB4-4502-A73C-2BDAEC4B215A)      
]
coclass CoWinService
    {
        [default] interface IWinService;
    };
}
```

The WinService internally expects that **vCallBack**.vt = VT_DISPATCH, i.e., that is the callback pointer I need to pass in when I invoke the WinServiceCOMfunction from my ConsoleClient.EXE app. WinService knows the name of the function that acts as callback. I.e., WinService calls from the IDispatch-pointer-callback GetIDsOfName with "**FunctionCallback**" as parameter. However, here I am getting different errors in the WinService like: No implemented, RPC is unavailable, etc.. Then no callback is executed (the ConsoleClient does not receive anything back).

What I have done so far (all the following source code is found in the ConsoleClient.EXE)
ConsoleClient.EXE main.cpp:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);

    //To be brief: Let's think that I already have an IDispatch pointer to the WinService interface IWinService:
    CComPtr<IDispatch> pIWinService; //pIWinService
    //Here I queried the IWinService interface...It was successful!!!

    OLECHAR * winServiceNameFunction = L"WinServiceCOMfunction";

    DISPID dispid;
    hr = pIWinService->GetIDsOfNames( IID_NULL, &winServiceNameFunction, 1, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, &dispid );

    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        wprintf( L"GetIDsOfNames failed" );
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf( L"GetIDsOfNames succeeded!" );
    }

    CComPtr<IDispatch> consoleClientCallback( new CConsoleClientInterface() );
    CConsoleClientInterface *sanity = dynamic_cast<CConsoleClientInterface *>( consoleClientCallback.p );

    if ( nullptr == pAutoCallback )
    {
        wprintf( L"CConsoleClientInterface pointer failed\n" );
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf( L"CConsoleClientInterface pointer succeeded\n" );
    }

    DWORD dwRegister;
    hr = CoRegisterClassObject(CLSID_CoConsoleClient, consoleClientCallback.p, 
        CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTIPLEUSE, &dwRegister);

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"CoRegisterClassObject Failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"CoRegisterClassObject Succeeded\n");
    }

    CComVariant paramCallback( consoleClientCallback.Detach() );
    VARIANTARG varParams[] = { paramCallback };
    DISPPARAMS dispparams = { vArgs, NULL, 1, 0 };

    hr = pPtr->Invoke(
        dispid,
        IID_NULL,
        LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
        DISPATCH_METHOD,
        &dispparams,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL);

    if ( FAILED( hr ) )
    {
        wprintf( L"Invoke failed" );
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf( L"Invoke Succeeded" );
    }

    MSG msg;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    CoRevokeClassObject(dwRegister);
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

All the main is succesfully executed. However, I never get anything from the callback. When the WinService tries to QueryInterface from teh IDispatch pointer callback, it throws erros like: No implemented, RPC is unavailable, among others...

Template class to create the ConsoleClient IDispatch interface
From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/12/10425215.aspx

disInterfaceBase.h:

```
template<typename DispInterface>
class CDispInterfaceBase : public DispInterface
{
public:
CDispInterfaceBase() : m_cRef(1), m_dwCookie(0) { }

/* IUnknown */
IFACEMETHODIMP QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void **ppv)
{
    *ppv = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = E_NOINTERFACE;
    if (riid == IID_IUnknown || riid == IID_IDispatch ||
        riid == __uuidof(DispInterface))
    {
        *ppv = static_cast<DispInterface *>
            (static_cast<IDispatch*>(this));
        AddRef();
        hr = S_OK;
    }
    return hr;
}

IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) AddRef()
{
    return InterlockedIncrement(&m_cRef);
}

IFACEMETHODIMP_(ULONG) Release()
{
    LONG cRef = InterlockedDecrement(&m_cRef);
    if (cRef == 0) delete this;
    return cRef;
}

// *** IDispatch ***
IFACEMETHODIMP GetTypeInfoCount(UINT *pctinfo)
{
    *pctinfo = 0;
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

IFACEMETHODIMP GetTypeInfo(UINT iTInfo, LCID lcid,
    ITypeInfo **ppTInfo)
{
    *ppTInfo = nullptr;
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

IFACEMETHODIMP GetIDsOfNames(REFIID, LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
    UINT cNames, LCID lcid,
    DISPID *rgDispId)
{
    return E_NOTIMPL;
}

IFACEMETHODIMP Invoke(
    DISPID dispid, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags,
    DISPPARAMS *pdispparams, VARIANT *pvarResult,
    EXCEPINFO *pexcepinfo, UINT *puArgErr)
{
    if (pvarResult) VariantInit(pvarResult);
    return SimpleInvoke(dispid, pdispparams, pvarResult);
}

// Derived class must implement SimpleInvoke
virtual HRESULT SimpleInvoke(DISPID dispid,
    DISPPARAMS *pdispparams, VARIANT *pvarResult) = 0;

public:
    HRESULT Connect(IUnknown *punk)
    {
        HRESULT hr = S_OK;
        CComPtr<IConnectionPointContainer> spcpc;
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = punk->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&spcpc));
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = spcpc->FindConnectionPoint(__uuidof(DispInterface), &m_spcp);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
            hr = m_spcp->Advise(this, &m_dwCookie);
        }
        return hr;
    }

void Disconnect()
{
    if (m_dwCookie) {
        m_spcp->Unadvise(m_dwCookie);
        m_spcp.Release();
        m_dwCookie = 0;
    }
}

private:
    LONG m_cRef;
    CComPtr<IConnectionPoint> m_spcp;
    DWORD m_dwCookie;
};
```

The actual IDispatch implementation in the ConsoleClient
ConsoleClient.h

```
class CConsoleClientInterface : public CDispInterfaceBase<ICONSOLEINTERFACE>
{
public:

    CConsoleClientInterface() { }
    ~CConsoleClientInterface() { }

STDMETHODIMP GetIDsOfNames(REFIID, LPOLESTR *rgszNames,
        UINT cNames, LCID lcid,
        DISPID *rgDispId)
    {    
        HRESULT hr = E_FAIL;

    if(_wcsicmp(*rgszNames, L"FunctionCallback") == 0)
    {
        *rgDispId = 1;
        hr= S_OK;
    }
    else
    {
        hr= DISP_E_UNKNOWNINTERFACE;
    }

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        std::cout << L"FAILED\n";
    }

    return hr;
}

    HRESULT SimpleInvoke(
        DISPID dispid, DISPPARAMS *pdispparams, VARIANT *pvarResult)
    {
//      switch (dispid) 
//      {
//      case 4:
            std::cout << L"SimpleInvoke" << std::endl; //This is never printed (for the error that I am trying to figure out)
            HRESULT hr = FunctionCallback( pdispparams->rgvarg[1].intVal, pdispparams->rgvarg[0].parray );
//          break;
//      }
        return hr;
    }

    HRESULT FunctionCallback( LONG longValue, LPSAFEARRAY safearray )
    {
        //So simple, I just want that this value is printed in the ConsoleClient's console! Unfortunately this is not happening!
        std::cout << longValue << std::endl;

        return S_OK;
    }
};
```

And the ConsoleClient.idl

```
[
    object,
    uuid(CD08B160-558A-4251-885C-173A08A461F1),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    helpstring("ICONSOLEINTERFACE Interface"),
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface ICONSOLEINTERFACE : IDispatch{
    [id(1), helpstring("method FunctionCallback")] 
    HRESULT FunctionCallback([in] LONG longValue, [in] LPSAFEARRAY safeArray );
};
[
    uuid(F3445A9E-555B-4729-952B-8B72B8DB2E37),
    version(1.0),
    helpstring("ConsoleClientLib Help Lib")
]
library ConsoleClientLib 
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(EFF9EC78-3031-4558-9BA3-5B2641CCB304),
        helpstring("CoConsoleClient Class")
    ]
    coclass ConsoleClientInterface 
    {
        [default] interface ICONSOLEINTERFACE;
    };
};
```

I have created:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EFF9EC78-3031-4558-9BA3-5B2641CCB304} //CLSID
(Default) REG_SZ = C:\Program Files\Common Files\ConsoleClient.EXE
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{EFF9EC78-3031-4558-9BA3-5B2641CCB304}\LocalServer32
ThreadingModel REG_SZ = Both
```

Also I have registered the tlb using regtlibv12.exe

Sorry for the TOO LONG post, but COM forces me to do this, in particular that I am new with COM and I do not know where I can be making a mistake.

NOTE: I am sure that the Invoke (from the ConsoleClient.EXE) to the WinService COM function (WinServiceCOMfunction) is successful (I debugged it and hits inside this function after the Invoke).

NOTE2: I am sure that the WinService using the callback works. There are other implementations (in different programming languages) making use of this mechanism via the same Function (**WinServiceCOMfunction**) in WinService.

Any help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only `GetIDsOfNames` implementation in your code recognizes just one name, `"WinServiceCOMfunction"`; whereas the service supposedly calls it with `"FunctionCallback"`

Comment: `I am getting different errors` Are you saying that several runs of the exact same program produce different outcomes? With all due respect, I find this hard to believe. Exactly what error do you get when running the code you've shown?

Comment: @Igor: (1) ConsoleClient.EXE implements CConsoleClientInterface::FunctionCallbak. CConsoleClientInterface is an IDispatch. I create in the main an object of CConsoleClientInterface (consoleClientCallback). I use consoleClientCallback to CoRegisterClassObject and to pass this object in a VARIANT as parameter to the WinServiceCOMfunction (implemented in WinService) via Invoke. WinService uses the consoleClientCallback pointer as callback. (2) When WinServices uses consoleClientCallback->GetIDsOfNames with "FunctionCallback" to get the DISPID, most of the times I am getting "No implemented"

Comment: @IMR, Igor is right, your **base** `GetIDsOfNames` only works for the name `"WinServiceCOMfunction"`.  This base template class for dispatch interfaces is suited for callers that doesn't require `GetIDsOfNames`, as it should be the case for **known** compile-time dispinterfaces with predefined DISPIDs.  Anyway, I think you can simply leave `GetIDsOfNames` not implemented in the base template class (just like the blog post you copied that code from) and override it in derived classes when needed.

Comment: `When WinServices uses consoleClientCallback->GetIDsOfNames with "FunctionCallback" to get the DISPID, most of the times I am getting "No implemented"` Of course - most of the time, your implementation of `consoleClientCallback->GetIDsOfNames` returns `DISP_E_UNKNOWNINTERFACE`. What else did you expect?

Comment: I updated the code to implement GetIDsOfNames and return DISPID =1 when the function name in the parameter is "FunctionCallback", still I am not able to get it work. I appreciate your time. THanks

Comment: Now getting 0x800706BA after GetIDsOfNames in the WinService. A lookup of this error number says "The RPC server is unavailable." I don't understand!

Comment: `do {} while (true);` You can't do that. Your thread has joined a single-threaded apartment (by means of calling `CoInitialize`). An STA thread must run a message pump, retrieving and dispatching window messages in a timely manner - it can't just sit in a busy loop. Remote calls into an STA are implemented by posting messages to a hidden window created by COM on your thread. For details, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150777/

Comment: @Igor Thanks for the tip! I followed what you indicated me. I removed the do-while, and instead I added the message pump (GetMessage, TranslateMessage and DispatchMessage). My code in the question has been updated. Everything started to work! So, I would like to give your hint as valid answer. How can I do that?